# find an odd differentiable function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $f'(x) = e^{-x^2}$

Tags: analysis

find an odd differentiable function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $f'(x) = e^{-x^2}$

This is for my analysis course and we are studying power series; my attempt:

$e^x = \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{x^k}{k!}$ using this I got the power series $e^{-x^2} = \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\dfrac{x^{2k}}{k!}$ so I then calculated $f(x) = \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\dfrac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)(k!)}$ which is odd and differentiable

however I kind of have done this question *blindly*, assuming that $f'(x)$ can be written as a power series. I took a look at my notes and we had a corollary of a theorem which stated that given a power series with radius of convergence $R>0$, let $f:(-R,R) \to \mathbb{R}$ $f(x) = \displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ then $a_n = \dfrac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$.

In this case, we have say $e^{-x^2} = \displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\dfrac{x^{2n}}{n!}$ which has $R = \infty$, and $a_n = \dfrac{(-1)^n}{n!}$ but $\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n!} \not = \dfrac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$ so that means that $e^{-x^2}$ cannot be written as a power series? I don't understand why not - could someone show me an analytical way to approach this question?

Comment: $f(x)=\int_0^x e^{-t^2}\,dt$.

Comment: It just ain't true that $a_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}$, instead $a_{2n} = \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}$ while $a_i=0$ for $i$ odd.

Comment: @DavidMitra How did you get that?

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen So how would the corollary change?

Comment: You're asked to find an antiderivative. The definite integral will always give one if your function is continuous (as you have). All that's left to do is verify that it's odd (hence, the lower limit of $0$ was selected).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You correctly computed the (converging) power series in$~x$ for $e^{-x^2}$. It is the derivative of the power series $\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!(2n+1)}x^{2n+1}$, which also has infinite radius of convergence, so describes an analytic function. Since the constant term was chosen $0$, it satisfies the requirement of giving an odd function. This is $\frac{\sqrt\pi}2$ times the [error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function).

Comment: would it safe to say $\sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{(-1)^n}{n!(2n+1)}x^{2n+1} = \int_0^x e^{-t^2} \ dx$? Also, from your previous comment, I figured out that $a_{2n} = \dfrac{(-1)^n}{n!} = \dfrac{f^{(2n)}(0)}{(2n)!}$ Which does indeed mean it can be written as a power series

Comment: It is safe to say that the derivative of a convergent power series is given (inside the radius of convergence) by the convergent power series obtained by term-by-term differentiation. Now apply the (second) fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm having troubles understanding your answer. I know that the derivative of $\int_0^x e^{-t^2} \ dx$ gives the required result from the fundamental theorem of calculus, but I don't see how it's odd. Also, you said "since the constant term was chosen 0, .." are you talking about the power series of f(x) or the integral?

Comment: I'm not talking about any integral, except in the conclusion. The power series is odd because it only has odd degree terms. It converges everywhere, so it defines an odd analytic (in particular differentiable) function, whose derivative is given by the power series for $e^{-x^2}$, which of course converges to $e^{-x^2}$. So you found an odd function that is an antiderivative of $e^{-x^2}$, which is all that was asked for. But by the _second_ [fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Second_part) is it also $x\mapsto \int_0^x e^{-t^2} \ dt$.

Comment: Thank you, explained everything.